# ¿Qué significa [::-1]?

Tags: python, python-3.x

me preguntaba si podéis ayudarme a enter que significa `[::-1]`.

```
' '.join([x[::-1] for x in (palabra)])
```

Por ejemplo he visto esto para dar la vuelta a una palabra, pero no sé muy bien a que se refiere `x[::-1]`. ¿Podríais explicarmelo en ambos casos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es lo que se conoce como rebanado ([slicing](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-slice)), permite básicamente obtener un fragmento (rebanada) de algún objeto indizable, de los tipos estándar son (quitando clase abstractas de `abc` y si no me salto alguno):

- `list`
- `tuple`
- `str`
- `bytes`
- `range`
- `bytearray`
- `memoryview`
- `collections.UserList`
- `collections.UserTuple`
- `array.array`

### La sintaxis básica

```
[indice_inicial: indice_final]
```

Es decir, seleccionará desde el item con el indice inicial que indiquemos, hasta el elemento con el índice final (no incluido).

Podemos omitir parámetros, si se omite el índice inicial se toma desde el primer elemento (índice 0), si se omite el índice final se toma hasta el último elemento (incluido). Si se omiten los dos se seleccionan todos los elementos (*aclararemos esto después).

```
>>> cad = "abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz"

>>> cad[::]   # Seleccionamos todo, equivalente a cad[0:len(cad)]
"abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz"

>>> cad[5:]   # Desde el índice 5 hasta el final
"fghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz"

>>> cad[:5]   # Desde el incio hasta el índice 5 (no incluido)
"abcde"

>>> cad[2: 7] # Desde el índice 2 hasta el 5 (no incluido)
"cdefg"
```

### Los índices negativos

Por otro lado Python permite usar índices negativos, siendo -1 el índice del  último elemento, -2 el del penúltimo, etc:

```
>>> cad[-6: -2]
"uvwx"
```

### Indices fuera del rango válido

Hay que señalar que en caso de usar un valor de índice que supere los índices válidos  para el objeto no tenemos un `IndexError`, simplemente se obtienen los elementos posibles ignorando los índices que no existen:

```
>>> cad[0: 100000]
'abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz'

>>> cad[-100000: 5]
'abcde'
```

### El parámetro opcional step

Además tenemos un tercer parámetro, conocido como paso (`step`):

```
[indice_inicial: indice_final: paso]
```

Indica cuantos indices se deben saltar desde el actual para seleccionar el siguiente. Por ejemplo, si tenemos:

```
>>> cad[1:8:3]
"beh"
```

el primer índice es el 1 ("b"), el segundo es `1 + paso`, es decir 4 ("e"), el siguiente es `4 + paso`, es decir 7 ("h"), el siguiente es 10, pero no se incluye porque es mayor o igual a 8.

El paso puede ser negativo, pero la idea es la misma:

```
>>> cad[8:0:-3]
"ifc"
```

El primer índice es el 8 ("i") el siguiente es `8 + paso` (8 + -3) que sería 5 ("f"), el siguiente sería `5 + paso` (5 + -3) que es 2 ("c"), el siguiente sería -1 (`len(cad)`) pero no se incluye al ser mayor o igual 0.

### (*) Valores por defecto

Como se ha comentado, podemos dejar vacío el índice inicial el final o ambos. Además el parámetro paso es opcional. Si no se especifican, los valores que toma automáticamente por defecto son:

```
╔══════════════════════════════════╦═══════════════════╗
║            Parámetro             ║ Valor por defecto ║
╠══════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ indice_inicial con paso positivo ║ 0                 ║
╠══════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ indice_inicial con paso negativo ║ len(objeto)       ║
╠══════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ indice_final con paso positivo   ║ len(objeto)       ║
╠══════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ indice_final con paso negativo   ║ -1 - len(objeto)  ║
╠══════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ paso                             ║ 1                 ║
╚══════════════════════════════════╩═══════════════════╝
```

### Resumiendo

```
╔═══════════════════╦══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║     Notación      ║                          Selecciona                          ║
╠═══════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ [:]               ║ Todo                                                         ║
╠═══════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ [:stop]           ║ Desde el primer elemento hasta el anterior a `stop`          ║
╠═══════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ [start:]          ║ Desde `start` hasta el final                                 ║
╠═══════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ [start:stop]      ║ Desde `start` hasta el anterior a `stop`                     ║
╠═══════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ [start:stop:step] ║ Desde `start` hasta `stop - 1` tomando elementos cada `step` ║
╠═══════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ [::step]          ║ Todo pero tomando solo cada `step` elementos.                ║
╚═══════════════════╩══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

### ¿Qué retorna un slicing?

Todos los objetos nativos de Python que permiten slicing generan siempre una copia del objeto (copia superficial). Fuera de los tipos nativos esto no siempre es así, por ejemplo NumPy por lo general retorna una vista para ahorra memoria y tiempo de procesado.

Por eso podemos usar `[:]` para generar una copia superficial de una lista por ejemplo:

```
>>> l = [1, 2]
>>> id(l)
140210885396352
>>> l2 = l[:]
>>> id(l2)
140212305847936
```

Observase que es una copia superficial, la lista se copia pero los elementos que contiene no (copia en profundidad):

```
>>> id(l[0])
    140212305885423
>>> id(l2[0])
    140212305885423
```

### La sintaxis `[:]` y los objetos `slice`

Por último, decir que internamente `[:]` usa objetos `slice`, los cuales podemos genera directamente con el builtin [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice). Esto viene a veces muy bien para generar rebanados programáticamente.

### Tu caso concreto

En tu ejemplo tenemos:

```
[::-1]
```

Esto indica que se seleccione desde último elemento hasta el primero tomando todos los elementos, el resultado es que invertimos los elementos. Recordemos (*), en este caso (`step` negativo) el índice inicial es igual a `len` por defecto mientras que el final es `-1 - len`:

```
>>> cad[::-1]
'zyxwvutsrqpoñnmlkjihgfedcba'

>>> cad[len(cad): -1 - len(cad): -1]
'zyxwvutsrqpoñnmlkjihgfedcba'

>>> cad[slice(None, None, -1)]
'zyxwvutsrqpoñnmlkjihgfedcba'
```

El resultado es una **copia superficial del objeto con los mismos elementos pero en el orden inverso**.