# Recorrer letras de una cadena en python

Tags: python

```
a = input("Escribe alguna palabra  \n ") 
print(a)
longitud=len(a)
print(longitud)


for i in a:
    print(i)
```

Este codigo es sobre recorrer una cadena de alguna palabra, ya sea "perro" recorrerla de esta manera "operr" que la primera se vaya a la segunda, la segunda a la tercera y la ultima a la primera
Nose muy bien como hacerlo, tengo una ligera idea, estaba pensando en utilizar el ciclo for y la longitud para que se estuviera restando o sumando y pudiera recorrerse pero no tengo la menor idea de como  implementarlo.

Podria alguien darme algun consejo o alguna pista, nose, llevo rato buscando informacion y como manipular cadenas pero no encuentra alguna de esta manera

**Es opcional ayudarme, pero te lo agradeceria mucho(pd: ya me quiero cambiar de carrera, jajaja)**

Comment: Solo necesitas indizado y [slicing](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/341569/15089), Obtén el último elemento de la cadena índizando y concatenalo con el rebanado desde el primer índice hasta el antepenúltimo. O itera generando el rango de índices desde el -1 hasta el len(cadena) - 1...

Answer (score 0):

Si estás trabajando en Python eso es muy sencillo, basta con usar la función reversed.

```
a = input("Escribe alguna palabra  \n ") 
longitud=len(a)
print("Longitud:", longitud)

for i in reversed(a):
    print(i, end = '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Como comentó FJSevilla, utilizando slicing

```py
a = input("Escribe alguna palabra  \n ") 
print(a)
# perro

t = a[-1] + a[:-1]
print(t)
# operr
```