# Uso Treeview me aparece duplicada la primera columna

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.7

Tengo una treeview acá la diseño

```
# Tabla
self.tree = ttk.Treeview(height = 10, columns = ('#1', '#2', '#3', '#4', '#5', '#6', '#07'))
self.tree.grid(row =6, column = 0, columnspan = 4)

self.tree.column("#0", width=150, minwidth=150)
self.tree.column("#1", width=150, minwidth=150)
self.tree.column("#2", width=150, minwidth=150)
self.tree.column("#3", width=150, minwidth=150)
self.tree.column("#4", width=150, minwidth=150)
self.tree.column("#5", width=150, minwidth=150)
self.tree.column("#6", width=150, minwidth=150)
self.tree.column("#7", width=150, minwidth=150)

self.tree.heading('#0', text = 'ID', anchor = CENTER)
self.tree.heading('#1', text = '1er Nombre', anchor = CENTER)
self.tree.heading('#2', text = '2do Nombre', anchor = CENTER)
self.tree.heading('#3', text = '1er Apellido', anchor = CENTER)
self.tree.heading('#4', text = '2do Apellido', anchor = CENTER)
self.tree.heading('#5', text = 'Sexo', anchor = CENTER)
self.tree.heading('#6', text = 'Fecha Ult Asignacion', anchor = CENTER)
self.tree.heading('#7', text = 'Dias Ult Asignacion', anchor = CENTER)
```

Aqui la funcion para rellenarla

```
def get_products(self):
    #Limpiando la Tabla
    records = self.tree.get_children()
    for element in records:
        self.tree.delete(element)
    #consultando lo datos
    query = 'SELECT * FROM escuela ORDER BY fecha1 Desc'
    db_rows = self.run_query(query)
    #Rellenando los Datos
    for row in db_rows:
        self.tree.insert('', 0, text = row[0:1], value = row[0:8])
```

Mi problema es que la columna ID la primera me la repite 2 veces, he intentado con múltiples configuraciones y me la repite dos veces o si la cambio por ejemplo si uso esta:

```
for row in db_rows:
        self.tree.insert('', 0, text = row[0:0], value = row[0:8])
```

Entonces la primera columna queda vacía y corres todas las columnas, no entiendo como decirle que me coloque simplemente todas la columnas, gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás pasando bien los valores para la columna `ID` (`text`) en el primer caso (no en el segundo intento) y pasas mal los datos para el resto (`values`) en ambos intentos. Asumiendo que la primera columna de tu tabla SQLite sea la `ID` y que las siete siguientes se corresponden con las columnas restantes del TreeView, debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
self.tree.insert('', 0, text=row[0], value=row[1:8])
```

`text=row[0:1]` asigna una lista con la primera columna de la query, no es incorrecto, pero no necesitas slicing basta un simple indizado (`text=row[0]`). Por otro lado `row[0:8]` es un rebanado que incluye desde la primera columna hasta la octava, pero la primera no debes incluirla. Al hacerlo desplazas todas las columnas quedando `Dias Ult Asignacion` con la columna con la fecha y los días no se muestran, debes pasar de la segunda a la octava, `row[1:8]`.

En tu segundo intento, `row[0:0]` genera una lista vacía.

También podrías hacer simplemente:

```
self.tree.insert('', 0, text=row[0], value=row[1:])
```

o desempaquetando:

```
for id_col, *cols_res  in db_rows:
    self.tree.insert('', 0, text=id_col, value=cols_res)
```

Para más información sobre el rebanado (slicing):

- [¿Qué significa [::-1]?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/341559/15089)

Comment: Muchas Gracias, ya me funciono y entendí la sixtansis  con la excelente explicación, muy agradecido FJSevilla