# ¿Existe alguna funcion "built in" que devuelva los últimos "n" caracteres de un string en Python?

Tags: python, string

Quiero saber si existe alguna funcion pre-armada que al pasarle un string y un numero "n", supongamos 2, me devuelva un string con las últimas dos letras.

```
cadena = "laguna"
#quiero las últimas dos letras
q= cadena[-2]+cadena[-1]
print(q)
#Imprime "na"
```

He encontrado solución concatenando el último y anteultimo caracter y definiendo la función yo mismo pero quería quitarme la duda. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Pregunta intimamente relacionada sobe el rebanado (que es la solución a tu pregunta): [¿Qué significa \[::-1\]?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/341559/15089)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Más que una función, con el acceso a las posiciones de un `string` sería suficiente:

```
print(cadena[-2:])
```

Esta sentencia viene a significar:

> "Queremos obtener el `substring` (o subcadena dentro del string) desde *dos posiciones antes de terminar el
>   string* `-2` hasta *el final del string* (`:` final por defecto)".

Puntos clave para su comprensión:

**El símbolo negativo** nos permite indicar que queremos comenzar a contar desde la posición final del `string`.

**El carácter `:`** nos permite indicar que vamos a efectuar una selección de la cadena, siendo la parte previa a los dos puntos la posición inicial y, la parte posterior, la posición  final de nuestra selección. Por ejemplo, estas dos operaciones proporcionarían el mismo resultado, solo que partiendo de sentidos inversos:

```
print(cadena[0:2]) "la"
print(cadena[-6:-4]) "la"
```

Si no establecemos ningún valor **previo al carácter `:`** por defecto comenzará en 0. Mientras que, si no establecemos ningún valor **posterior al carácter `:`** tomará como valor final el último. Como ejemplo y, retomando el anterior, podemos apreciar como estas cuatro operaciones, devuelven el mismo resultado:

```
print(cadena[:]) "laguna"
print(cadena[0:]) "laguna"
print(cadena[:6]) "laguna"
print(cadena[0:6]) "laguna"
```

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar la sintaxis de `[:]`? Es decir, qué significa el número que va delante de los dos puntos, detrás de los dos puntos, qué siginifica si el número es positivo/negativo y qué significa el no poner nada en uno de los lados?

Comment: Por supuesto @ordago-QUÉDATEENCASA, he ampliado la respuesta para que pueda resultar más comprensible.

Comment: @Grommy genial, gracias por el esfuerzo, con estas indicaciones la respuesta es ahora de 10

Comment: Me alegro que te sirva de ayuda @ordago-QUÉDATEENCASA, gracias a ti.

Comment: Como agregado, podemos mencionar que existe un tercer argumento que podemos añadir, es decir [ Start : Stop : Step ] donde Step es el "paso" o "salteo" del "puntero" de posición. Ejemplos:
`print(cadena[::2])   "lgn"`
`print(cadena[::-2])   "aua"`