# Obtener el promedio cada n valores de una lista en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, lista, arraylist

estoy tratando de obtener el promedio de una lista pero de 5 en 5 elementos, es decir: 
 `Lista=[ 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1]`(mi lista es aleatoria, esta es un ejemplo) y obtener el promedio de 5 en 5 elementos, para guardarlos dentro de otra lista, de tal manera que me quede así: `Lista_promedio=[ 0.3  0.6  0.6  0.2 ]`, adjunto el código que estoy usando.

```
import numpy as np

pure=np.random.randint(2, size=100)
pure=pure.tolist()

p=[]
for x in range(0,len(pure), 5):
    y=sum(pure[x])/5
    p.append(y)
print(p)
```

pero me salta un error de:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Cualquier ayuda, sugerencia u cambio en el código es bien recibida, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que aplicar `sum` sobre un [rebanado de la lista](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/341569/15089) que contenga los 5 elementos, ahora lo aplicas  sobre un solo elemento, el que tiene índice `x` en esa iteración. Como `sum` espera un iterable y le pasas un entero tienes la esperada excepción:

> ```
> >>> sum(13)
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
> ```

Debería ser por tanto:

```
p = []
for x in range(0, len(pure), 5):
    y = sum(pure[x: x + 5]) / 5
    p.append(y)
print(p)
```

> ```
> [0.6, 0.4, 0.4, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.4, 1.0, 0.8, 0.4,
>  0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.4, 1.0, 0.4, 0.6, 0.4, 0.6, 0.2]
> ```

O ya que usas NumPy, deberías seguir haciéndolo en el resto del código:

```
pure = np.random.randint(2, size=100)
p = np.reshape(pure, (-1, 5)).sum(axis=1) / 5
```

> ```
> >>> p
> array([0.6, 0.4, 0.4, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.4, 1. , 0.8, 0.4,
>        0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.4, 1. , 0.4, 0.6, 0.4, 0.6, 0.2])
> ```

Comment: Muchas gracias, seguí la linea con la iteración x+5, me sirvió mucho!