# Doble bucle for en Python. Como va trabajando internamente?

Tags: python, bucle-for

por favor si alguien fuera tan amable de ayudarme a comprender como funcionan los bucles que tienen dos for dentro de la funcion y como se va desarrollando.

```
for i , frag in enumerate(fragments):
     frag = [frag[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(frag), 3)]
     for j,atr in enumerate(atributos):
        xx[i,j] = frag.count(atr)
```

donde fragments es una lista de 101.800 datos y atributos es una lista de 64.

la sentencia que no se como leer, es donde crea xx[i,j] = frag.count(atr)

Mil gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo mejor es crear un ejemplo reproducible pero más manejable que tu caso real.

- No se si `fragments` y `atributos` son listas o arrays de NumPy (realmente es irrelevante). Tampoco se puede deducir el tipo, solo que es iterable o es un array bidimensional. Pero importa poco, para el ejemplo voy a usar cadenas por legibilidad.
- En cambio `xx` asumo que es un array de NumPy por la sintaxis al indizar. Sus dimensiones deben ser de al menos `len(fragments)` x `len(atributos)`. El tipo en principio debería ser entero.

El ejemplo sería:

```
import numpy as np


fragments = ["aggacgagggagagg",
             "acggccacgtgaggt",
             "ggctgccggtaaggt"]

atributos = ["agg", "ggt", "acg"]
xx = np.empty(
    (len(fragments), len(atributos)), 
    dtype=int
    )

for i , frag in enumerate(fragments):
     frag = [frag[i: i+3] for i in range(0, len(frag), 3)]
     for j, atr in enumerate(atributos):
        xx[i,j] = frag.count(atr)
```

Paso a paso:

- **`for i , frag in enumerate(fragments):`** gracias a `enumerate` iteramos sobre `fragments`, obteniendo cada elemento en la variable `frag` y su índice en la variable `i`.
- **`frag = [frag[i: i+3] for i in range(0, len(frag), 3)]`**: en éste caso estamos ante una lisa por compresión. Lo que hace es partir cada fragmento en grupos de tres items [haciendo uso de rebanado (slicing)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/341559/15089):

  ```
  "aggacgagggagagg" --> ['agg', 'acg', 'agg', 'gag', 'agg']
  "acggccacgtgaggt" --> ['acg', 'gcc', 'acg', 'tga', 'ggt']
  "ggctgccggtaaggt" --> ['ggc', 'tgc', 'cgg', 'taa', 'ggt']
  ```
- **`for j, atr in enumerate(atributos):`** vuelve a hacer uso de `enumerate` para recorrer en éste caso la lista/array `atributos`. Al estar éste `for` anidado dentro del primero, por cada fila/item de `fragments` se recorre atributos al completo.
- **`xx[i,j] = frag.count(atr)`** --> ésta línea lo que hace básicamente es contar cuantas veces cada item de `atributos` está en el fragmento previamente partido cada tres items. El número de veces que dicho atributo aparece como subfragmento de longitud 3 del fragmento se almacena en la matriz `xx` usando `i` como índice para la fila y `j` para la columna.

Los pasos por tanto son:

1. Primera iteración del primer ciclo (`i = 0`, `frag=['agg', 'acg', 'agg', 'gag', 'agg']`):

   ```
   xx[0, 0] = ['agg', 'acg', 'agg', 'gag', 'agg'].count("agg") = 3
   xx[0, 1] = ['agg', 'acg', 'agg', 'gag', 'agg'].count("ggt") = 0
   xx[0, 2] = ['agg', 'acg', 'agg', 'gag', 'agg'].count("acg") = 1
   ```
2. Segunda iteración del primer ciclo (`i = 1`, `frag=['acg', 'gcc', 'acg', 'tga', 'ggt']`):

   ```
   xx[1, 0] = ['acg', 'gcc', 'acg', 'tga', 'ggt'].count("agg") = 0
   xx[1, 1] = ['acg', 'gcc', 'acg', 'tga', 'ggt'].count("ggt") = 1
   xx[1, 2] = ['acg', 'gcc', 'acg', 'tga', 'ggt'].count("acg") = 2
   ```
3. Tercera iteración del primer ciclo (`i = 3`, `frag= ['ggc', 'tgc', 'cgg', 'taa', 'ggt']`):

   ```
   xx[2, 0] = ['ggc', 'tgc', 'cgg', 'taa', 'ggt'].count("agg") = 0
   xx[2, 1] = ['ggc', 'tgc', 'cgg', 'taa', 'ggt'].count("ggt") = 1
   xx[2, 2] = ['ggc', 'tgc', 'cgg', 'taa', 'ggt'].count("acg") = 0
   ```

Por lo que el resultado final es:

> ```
> >>> xx
>
> array([[3, 0, 1],
>        [0, 1, 2],
>        [0, 1, 0]])
> ```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por el tiempo y la gran explicacion. Respecto a for anidado, entiendo que xx[i,j] esta creando un array donde la fila serian los indices de los fragmentos y el j seria las columnas de cada atributo, dejando como dato la cuenta de cada registro en la matriz?. De verdad muchas gracias

Comment: Hola Jaime, si, así es, pero un matiz, la matriz no se crea en esa linea, en esa linea solo se indiza para acceder a la celda oportuna y asignarle un valor. La matriz debe estar creada antes ya que no se puede indizar sobre un elemento que no existe previamente. En el los dos for solo se rellena con datos digamos, en mi ejemplo la matriz se crea en `xx = np.empty(...)`, dónde solo se reserva memoria para los items pero no se inicializa (matriz con valores basura). Es resto es tal como comentas. Saludos.

Comment: Perfecto. Muy agradecido! Slds