# ¿Para qué sirven los dos puntos ":" en un array en Numpy? (python)

Tags: python, numpy

¿Alguien me puede explicar cómo funcionan los dos puntos ":" en un array? Como en la siguiente expresión: `np.sum(y[1:n:2])`. Entiendo que es un sumatorio de los números de un array pero no entiendo la estructura.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Qué significa \[::-1\]?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/341559/qu%c3%a9-significa-1)

Answer (score 2):

Los dos puntos ":" en un array en Python se utilizan para especificar un intervalo. En este caso, se está sumando los elementos del array en el intervalo desde el elemento 1 hasta el elemento n, con un salto de 2 en 2 elementos. Por lo tanto, se está sumando todos los elementos del array que ocupan las posiciones 1, 3, 5, ... hasta la posición n.

La sintaxis general para especificar un intervalo en un array en Python es la siguiente:

```
array[inicio:fin:salto]
```

Donde **inicio** es la posición inicial del intervalo (incluida), **fin** es la posición final del intervalo (excluida) y **salto** es el número de elementos que se saltan al seleccionar el siguiente elemento del intervalo. Si se omite alguno de estos tres elementos, se tomarán los valores por defecto: `inicio = 0`, `fin = longitud del array` y `salto = 1`.

Por lo tanto, en el ejemplo dado, se está sumando los elementos del array "y" desde la posición 1 hasta la posición n, con un salto de 2 en 2 elementos. Esto se traduce en la suma de todos los elementos que ocupan las posiciones 1, 3, 5, ... hasta la posición n en el array.

Comment: Entiendo, muchas gracias!

Comment: Como curiosidad, en realidad, x[inicio:fin:paso] es azucar sintactica para x[slice(inicio, fin, paso)]